# How do i update a collection of objects with the entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two entities: **Question** and **Multiple_Choice_Question**. A Question object has a list of Multiple_Choice_Question objects. To edit these objects, I pass the Question and the list of Multiple_Choice_Question objects to a ViewModel that displays them on my asp.net website.

On [HttpPost], i get the question object from the DBContext and change the old properties with the new ones from the ViewModel. Then DBContext.SaveChanges(); updates.

To update the Multiple_Choice_Question list i do the following:

```
                foreach (MCQ newmcqq in model.MCQ)
            {
                Multiple_Choice_Question item = new Multiple_Choice_Question();
                item = db.Multiple_Choice_Question.First(x => x.mcq_id == newmcqq.mcq_id);
                item.mcq_id = newmcqq.mcq_id;
                item.choice_number = newmcqq.choice_number.ToString();
                item.choice_wording = newmcqq.choice_wording;
                item.help_text = newmcqq.help_text;
            }
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping and updating individual items is the only way with LINQ. It really isn't intended for batch `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

You're calling `SaveChanges()` outside the loop, so that's good. Still this is only scalable to a certain point. You'll eventually run into performance issues with it.